# How to hold a css style on hover

Tags: javascript, css, hover

I have a menu and I'm added it's minimised code here.I wish to show the sub menu when user hover on the `<a>` tag associated with it.here the problem is => when I hover on `<a>` tag it's showing sub menu but when I try to select a sub menu item it's disappear.How can I fix this?

```css
.nav-sec-level{
  opacity:0;
  border:1px solid #000;
  }

a:hover + ul.nav-sec-level{
  opacity:1;
  }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="side-bar">
  <a>gh kl</a>
  <ul class="nav-sec-level">some menu
    <li>jdfs</li>
    <li>jdfs</li>
    <li>jdfs</li>
  </ul>
</li>

<li class="side-bar">
  <a>gh kl</a>
  <ul class="nav-sec-level">some menu
    <li>jdfs</li>
    <li>jdfs</li>
    <li>jdfs</li>
  </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

**Note :** I can apply the hover property only for the `<a>` tag.

Comment: you should use hover on li tag with side-bar class

Comment: @chiller but if you applied so the menu will show even if you hovered the `<ul>` tag

Comment: you have to use display:none and block instead of opacity

Comment: Do you specifically want a blank space where each sub menu will be (as in your demo)? That's kind of an unusual layout...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.nav-sec-level{
  background: red;
  border:1px solid #000;
  display: none;
 }

.side-bar:hover .nav-sec-level{
   display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="side-bar">
  <a>gh kl</a>
  <ul class="nav-sec-level">some menu
    <li>jdfs</li>
    <li>jdfs</li>
    <li>jdfs</li>
  </ul>
</li>

<li class="side-bar">
  <a>gh kl</a>
  <ul class="nav-sec-level">some menu
    <li>jdfs</li>
    <li>jdfs</li>
    <li>jdfs</li>
  </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this code, this how usually submenu works

```css
li.side-bar{
  position:relative;
  transition: all .5s;
}

.nav-sec-level{
  border:1px solid #000;
  position:absolute;
  top:100%;
  display:none;
  background:#fff;
  z-index:111;
  
  }

li.side-bar:hover > ul.nav-sec-level{
  display:block;
  }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="side-bar">
  <a>gh kl</a>
  <ul class="nav-sec-level">some menu
    <li>jdfs</li>
    <li>jdfs</li>
    <li>jdfs</li>
  </ul>
</li>

<li class="side-bar">
  <a>gh kl</a>
  <ul class="nav-sec-level">some menu
    <li>jdfs</li>
    <li>jdfs</li>
    <li>jdfs</li>
  </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.nav-sec-level{
  display:none;
  border:1px solid #000;
  }
a:hover + ul.nav-sec-level{
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="side-bar">
  <a>gh kl</a>
  <ul class="nav-sec-level">some menu
    <li>jdfs</li>
    <li>jdfs</li>
    <li>jdfs</li>
  </ul>
</li>

<li class="side-bar">
  <a>gh kl</a>
  <ul class="nav-sec-level">some menu
    <li>jdfs</li>
    <li>jdfs</li>
    <li>jdfs</li>
  </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

I hope it will work fine.

Comment: The edit didn't help.  When you move the mouse over the sub-menu it disappears, just as it did with the OP's code...

Answer (score 0):

So, that's happening because you are removing your cursor from the "a" element when you try to go to the submenu. A quick fix for that is just change your :hover to the "li" element and replace the opacity property to display.

Something like that:

```css
.nav-sec-level{
  display:none;
  border:1px solid #000;
  }

li:hover ul.nav-sec-level{
  display: block;
  }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="side-bar">
  <a>gh kl</a>
  <ul class="nav-sec-level">some menu
    <li>jdfs</li>
    <li>jdfs</li>
    <li>jdfs</li>
  </ul>
</li>

<li class="side-bar">
  <a>gh kl</a>
  <ul class="nav-sec-level">some menu
    <li>jdfs</li>
    <li>jdfs</li>
    <li>jdfs</li>
  </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: but if you applied so the menu will show even if you hovered the <ul> tag

Comment: No, because the :hover is in the <li>, not in the <ul>.

Comment: OP means if you move the mouse over the invisible ul that is the anchor's sibling.

Comment: Oh, I see you point. In that case, just change the opacity:0; to display: none;

Comment: I just edited the code snippet. If you want to keep the opacity for some reason, you can also add another CSS property called visibility (visible|hidden).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `:hover` on `a` use it on `li`, this way your submenu(`.nav-sec-level`) will also be a part of `li` so it will remain open on hover.

```css
.nav-sec-level{
  display: none;
  border:1px solid #000;
  }

li:hover ul.nav-sec-level{
  display: block;
  }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="side-bar">
  <a>gh kl</a>
  <ul class="nav-sec-level">some menu
    <li>jdfs</li>
    <li>jdfs</li>
    <li>jdfs</li>
  </ul>
</li>

<li class="side-bar">
  <a>gh kl</a>
  <ul class="nav-sec-level">some menu
    <li>jdfs</li>
    <li>jdfs</li>
    <li>jdfs</li>
  </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: but if you applied so the menu will show even if you hovered the <ul> tag

Comment: yes you are right, instead of opacity use display: none and block, I'll edit it.

Comment: Yes now its almost exactly same as the approved answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please apply following style instead of your style :

```
.nav-sec-level
{   
   border:1px solid #000;
   display:none;
   position:absolute;
   background-color:#CCCCCC;
 }

.side-bar:hover ul.nav-sec-level
{
  display:block;    
}
```

No changes in HTML code.

Thanks...